# trying to show mqtt message as toast

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

Hi I am trying to get the message from mqtt broker as a toast, but I keep getting an error for the Toast (red underline in the code), could someone please let me know how to amend this?

here is the code

```
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;



import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MqttCallback{
    MqttClient client;
    private String clientInfo = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    //private final MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();


    public void findSpace(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //adapted from https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/persist/MemoryPersistence.html
        try {
            MemoryPersistence mp = new MemoryPersistence();
            client = new MqttClient("tcp://10.150.37.228:1883", clientInfo, mp);
            MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOps = new MqttConnectOptions();
            mqttConnectOps .setCleanSession(true);
            client.connect(mqttConnectOps );
            client.setCallback(this);
            client.subscribe("test");
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(message);
        CharSequence cs = new String(message.getPayload());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the error? What does `message.getPayload()` return?

Comment: @bigdestroyer the message from the broker

Comment: I mean the value. Check Omid Zamani answer. You code doesn't even compile. Show the error.

Comment: Toast needs a Android context variable as well the text and show duration

Comment: you should remove your async task and put your mqtt inside the activity.
Set up mqtt in onCreate and implement MqttCallback in your Activity. The reason why it didnt show is because the AsyncTask has finish.

Comment: @Spurdow how would I connect to the mqtt broker without Async Task?

Comment: @Spurdow thanks I have removed the async task and it is connected via the on create method but still cannot display the toast

Comment: Use the context the activity is using MainActivity.this or this

Comment: And be sure that you are subscribed

Comment: The MQTT client connection should be done in an async task because it does network IO so should NOT be done on the main/UI thread

Comment: @hardillb yes that is true, but the op wants to see the toast regardless of how the connection should be implemented

Comment: @Spurdow yes i am, the message is showing in the console but not in the toast

Comment: Then you have successfully connected and subscribed, now leave the app as is, and send a message again

Comment: Toast still isn't working, please see the updated code

Comment: btw add some code to reconnect when `connectionLost` happens like these

`void connect(){
MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOps = new MqttConnectOptions();
            mqttConnectOps .setCleanSession(true);
            client.connect(mqttConnectOps );
            client.setCallback(this);
            client.subscribe("test");
}`

`connectionLost(){
 connect();
}`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message.getPayload(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

`message.getPayload()` is an array of bytes docs here https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttMessage.html#getPayload()

you should do this instead

If you are in activity

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,new String(message.getPayload()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i am doing it in Async Task. that is not working either

Comment: hmm, are you using it inside the `doInBackground`?

Comment: ok, you must show your code so that we can fix it., But your question is about red underline in the code, Toast.makeText doesnt require an array of bytes instead it requires a `CharacterSequence`. If it doesnt show and it compiles and run then you must understand that Toast runs in the main thread.

Comment: wait sorry where am I making my mqtt message final and where am I putting the code you just posted?

Comment: so everytime you receive a message you run a AsyncTask? btw show all your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use RunOnUithread. You should use a Handler which could communicate asynchronously between main thread and other threads.

anyway, this could not work.

```
Toast.makeText(this,new String(message.getPayload()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

"this" is the runnable object and not the activity context. So you should pass the context instead of "this". And you have to pass a CharSequence instead of a string. This could work:

```
CharSequence cs = new String(message.getPayload());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Edit:
Thanks Spurdow for your hint that a AppCompatActivity is used and instead of "getApplicationContext()" the following should be used.

```
CharSequence cs = new String(message.getPayload());
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Am I putting this in the mesage arrived method? Because although the error is gone, I am not seeing anything, in the toast.

Comment: Your first problem is gone, so you have to change your implementation and use Handlers.

Comment: at least give me some credit when you copied my answer :)

Comment: at first the op only showed the messageArrived function, and then when he showed `MainActivity`, then just put `MainActivity.this` instead of `this`

Comment: never read your comment, but sorry :)

it seems he is using a fragment so maybe getActivity() would be better.

Comment: @ChampS wrong, he is actually using `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @Spurdow the Toast still does not show up, i just cannot workout why